# not equals is not working in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the below:

```
testval         =   node[:test][:val1]


if #{testval} != "true"
log "### #{testval} : inside if"
end
```

It is always getting inside the if condition even when the value is true. Please help.

Comment: Have you ever tried your code? There is a syntax error for the if. `#{..}` is normally used inside a string. What is `node`? What should testval be? And be aware: `true` is not the same as the string `"true"`.

Comment: You don't even have to try the code. Even the extremely stupid syntax highlighter right here on StackOverflow shows the error very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

`#{}` is for string interpolation.

```
if testval != "true" 
   log "### #{testval} : inside if" 
end
```